# Why are knockout view models being instantiated twice?

Tags: knockout.js

I have a js file I'm planning to use to control 2 view models in an app.  It calls applyBindings once for each VM.  Note the console.log line:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var currentFolder; // not used yet

    function initializeData(folder) {

        console.log('app.js initializing to ' + folder);

        // Get containers for binding view models
        var foldersContainer = document.getElementById('foldersPanel');
        var filesContainer = document.getElementById('filesPanel');        

        // Create view models
        var folderViewModel = new FolderViewModel(folder);
        var fileViewModel = new FileViewModel(folder);

        // Initialize list view models
        // folderViewModel.initialize();
        // fileViewModel.initialize();

        // Bind view model to view
        ko.applyBindings(folderViewModel, foldersContainer);
        ko.applyBindings(fileViewModel, filesContainer);
    }

    initializeData(rootFolder); // rootfolder = global set in cshtml to web.config appSetting
    })();
```

Here's one of the view models.  The other one is almost identical.  Again,   Note the console.log line:

```
function Folder(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = name;
}

function FolderViewModel(folder) {

    console.log('FolderViewModel.js received folder: ' + folder);
    var self = this;

    self.folders = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.currentFolder = ko.observable(folder);

    $.getJSON('/api/folders', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            self.folders.push(new Folder(value.Name));
        });
    });
}

function onFolderClicked(folder) {
    self.currentFolder(self.currentFolder() + '/' + folder.Name);
    console.log(self.currentFolder());
}
```

And here is the console output from loading the page (once).  What could be causing the instantiation of the view model for the second time, where the 'folder' parameter is undefined?

- app.js initializing to FileStorage
- FolderViewModel.js received folder: FileStorage
- FolderViewModel.js received folder: undefined

Comment: Any chance you have a duplicate `console.log` in `FileViewModel`?

Comment: Good thought, but the console.log in FileViewModel is doing the same thing - logging "FileViewModel.js received FileStorage", "FileViewModel.js received undefined"

Comment: Maybe something outside the code you added is causing an issue?  I can't reproduce with this slightly modified version of your code: https://jsfiddle.net/tLutt85p/

Comment: is one of you html elements a child of the other one? In which case apply bindings might be getting called twice on the child

Comment: What version on Knockout are you using?

Comment: I am using 3.4.2.  Thank you all for your comments, however I should mention I have gone a different approach where everything is consolidated into one ViewModel and I am no longer having this problem.